# Calling a web service under the WSS virtual directory gets 401 unauthorized

Tags: wss-3.0, web-services

I have a simple web service that is in a virtual directory under a WSS 3.0 web app virtual directory. If I log on to the box and use IE to execute the web service it works. If I write a web part it fails with:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized
```

The really strange thing is that it works in production, but not the new test server! I have looked at both web.configs and IIS settings and see no differences. Both boxes are running Server08, IIS7 and WSS 3.0 (12.0.0.6421).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the loopback issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: looks like you sniped me....

Comment: Sad thing is that I knew about this and did not check it because I thought I already had!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some additional details that may be of value.  http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx